# How to format time to HH:mm according to a specefic local using fns

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

I want to format this date type : '2022-10-19T18:30:00.000+02:00' (exemple) to 'HH:mm' using fns according to a specefic local.

```
let slot = '2022-10-19T18:30:00.000+02:00';
console.log(fns.format(new Date("2022-10-19T18:30:00.000+02:00"), "HH:mm", { locale: fr }))
```

This always give me the same output no matter what the local is.

What to do in order to get the time according to a local ?

Comment: Do you mean timezone instead of locale?

Comment: Yes something like that, I'm tryin to get hour according to a specefic timezone or place.